# How to prevent css grid elements from making a black line when overflowed from the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

I'm trying to create a semicircle as a container of a grid having a lot of elements.

```css
.circle {
  /* this is for sqaures */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 25px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 25px);
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  height: 40vh;
  width: 80vh;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  border-radius: 40vh 40vh 0px 0px;
}

.squares {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLiUS.png)

But when the grid elements overflow the semicircle which is its container then they make a black line in the bottom. How to prevent it and make the grid continue in the vertical direction.

Also, I need the boxes to be square only and the width of the grid should be as it is but height may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to the .circle selector:

```
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
```

You can also check it here:
https://codepen.io/serazoltan/pen/bGYRqjg